# How to requeue request for UIView drawRect for manual "Animations"

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, ios

I am trying to do some *manual* "Animation" within a `UIview`.

I put "Animation" in quotes, in that I am trying to animate movement and display of arbitrary elements which I control - rather than clear and concise movements that are typically done through the UIView Animation blocks. (Think of making a guy walk - as I am drawing different images and different places as a series of "frames".)

This would be simple do to in Cocos2d, using "nextFrame" - which is continuously re-queued.

I figured I could do drawing inside drawRect, and the `setNeedsDisplay` at the end of `drawRect`, which would make the framework immediately send another `drawRect` event - but this doesn't seem to work.

I could set up an `NSTimer` event to `setNeedsDisplay` at a regular time interval, but this would not allow me to draw at the maximum possible frame rate.

I also tried doing this with layoutSubviews, calling setNeedsLayout at the end of `layoutSubviews` - but I could never acu

So - how can I do this?

Comment: why wouldnt an nstimer give you the max frame rate?

Comment: You mean if I just requested a one-shot timer event to fire *immediately*? Hadn't thought of that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an NSTimer to fire an update request, at the max frame rate, as discussed.